# Trying to create some multi-state buttons in Flash CS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, adobe

Ok, so I have a page with 4 buttons on it. Each button is a separate movie file with 3 frames: an UP (1) frame, an OVER (2) frame, and a DOWN (3) frame. What I want to happen is when you mouseover the button it lights up (display the OVER frame) and when you click it expands (display the DOWN frame) and sticks so when you move the mouse away the DOWN frame remains displayed, but if you click the button again, it should go back to its UP state. I currently have the following code:

```
int1btn.stop();

int1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onBtnPress);
int1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onBtnOver);
int1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onBtnOut);

function onBtnPress(event:MouseEvent):void

{
    int1btn.gotoAndStop(3);
}

function onBtnOver(event:MouseEvent):void

{

    if (int1btn.currentFrame != 3)

    {

        int1btn.gotoAndStop(2);

    }

}

function onBtnOut(event:MouseEvent):void

{
    if (int1btn.currentFrame != 1)
    {
        int1btn.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

This code does everything I want but the last part. The way it works now is that when I hover the UP and OVER frames alternate just fine, when I click, the DOWN frame displays, but when I MOUSEOUT the DOWN frame goes away instead of sticking. I want that DOWN frame to stay until I click the button again. EVEN BETTER would be if the DOWN frame displayed until I clicked one of the other buttons. I found this code on another site and have been modifying it, I don't know much at all about code and I am building this for work which has limited internet access to helpful sites and videos. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onBtnOut`, you should be checking to see that it's not on the `DOWN` state before returning it to the `UP` state. Additionally, you'll want to handle your press differently based on whether the button is in the `DOWN` or `OVER` state:

```
int1btn.stop();

int1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onBtnPress);
int1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onBtnOver);
int1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onBtnOut);

function onBtnPress(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // toggle between frame 1 and 3 on button press
    int1btn.gotoAndStop(int1btn.currentFrame == 3 ? 1 : 3);
}

function onBtnOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    if (int1btn.currentFrame != 3)

    {

        int1btn.gotoAndStop(2);

    }

}

function onBtnOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // only switch back to UP state if the button is "pressed"
    if (int1btn.currentFrame != 3)
    {
        int1btn.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, please remember to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

On your onBtnOut handler, there is no condition stopping it from going back to its up state if it's down. You would have to either add another condition forcing it to be NOT on its up state and NOT on its down state, or just change your existing condition to checking that it's on its over state.

Here:
You can either, depending on what you need, use:

```
function onBtnOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if (int1btn.currentFrame == 2){
        int1btn.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Or you can use:

```
function onBtnOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if (int1btn.currentFrame != 1 && int1btn.currentFrame != 2){
        int1btn.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```